# GCC, ARM and byte-wise load/store

Tags: c++, arm

Is there a way (e.g. a builtin-function) to make a byte-store (`strb`) using C/C++ with gcc?

For the following instruction gcc uses surely a 32-bit store(`str`) to the register.

```
USART1->TDR = 0x01;
```

This is correct, because the upper bits of the register are unused and get assigned `0` (the reset value as the ARM Ref-Manual states is correct).

Can one use a (builtin)-function of gcc to trigger a byte-store (`strb`) in ARM-Assembler?

Comment: Dereference a `volatile uint8_t *`?

Comment: What's the goal anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dereference a `uint8_t` pointer, a `strb` instruction will be generated.

```c
uint8_t* ptr = ...;
*ptr = 42;
```

Also see: https://godbolt.org/z/n8v1vcafz

You shouldn't do it for STM32 registers though as they must be accessed with word (32-bit) operations. Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Where do you get the info from, that accessing STM 32-Bit registers with `strb` results in UB? UB is a term of C / C++. I think you mean, it is not specified on the HW-side. Can you give me a reference, that this is not allowed an STM32 or other µC?

Comment: 32-bit access is the general rule. That's why all STM32 memory-mapped registers are defined as `volatile uint32_t*`. If half-word or even byte access is allowed, it is usually mentioned at the beginning of the *XXX register* chapter in the reference manual of the microcontroller. Search for "accessed". Remember: memory-mapped registers aren't implemented as memory. Instead, the peripheral listens on internal bus and acts if a relevant address appears.

Comment: Here is a link to the basic concepts of memory-mapped I/O: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102618/0100/Basic-concepts.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the docu hint! E.g. for the STM32G431 the SPI/I2S DR may be accessed bytewise, whereas the I2C and USART DR may not. Maybe a docu bug? Just tested for curiosity with a USART TDR and it works ...

Comment: Relying on undocumented behaviour is not good.  It may work now, but a die shrink/revision could change the behaviour.  Also, it may work on one version of the STM32, but not another as they rev'ed the module to follow the spec more closely.  Usually hardware references explicitly spells out access methods and you should follow the documentation.  If not, spell out in comments that you are violating the documents and give a rationale.  Don't just do it because you think it works.